# Is Student's $t$-test the right choice?

Tags: categorical-data, t-test, paired-comparisons

I have 2 patient populations taken from the same time period that underwent 2 different surgical laparoscopic procedures. I want to compare the rate of conversion to an open surgical procedure. In my data this is represented as dummy code under the variable OpenConversion. Can I do a *t*-test to compare the rates, or am I choosing the wrong test? Thanks!

Comment: Do the rates look normally distributed?

Comment: The sample sizes are too small to tell.

Comment: How small, exactly? When you say 'rate of conversion' are those proportions of counts?

Comment: As in less than a dozen for both procedure A and B. I think of them as proportions, but don't know if that is the right way to think about them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is conversion a binary (yes/no) variable? If so, you essentially have a [2-by-2 contingency table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table) (procedure being one of the variables, conversion the other), where you can test independence by for example $\chi^2$-test or [Fisher exact test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test).

Of course [correlation does not imply causation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_does_not_imply_causation), and in this example it might especially be worth considering whether the patient groups truly differed *only* in the fact that they recieved different treatments. (And not in their age-, sex-, disease severity etc. composition.) If you have information on such possible [confounding variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confounding), you might consider employing [logistic regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression).